# Redundant Data are added while creating an XML file from dataSet in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

**This is resultant Xml File**

```
<Drug_x0020_Type>Marijuana</Drug_x0020_Type>
<Marij_x0020_Type>Test1</Marij_x0020_Type>
<Test1_x0020_Type>Type1</Test1_x0020_Type> <Time_x0020__x002F__x0020_Date_x0020_Recv_x0027_d>11:30</Time_x0020__x002F__x0020_Date_x0020_Recv_x0027_d>
```

In Database these element are as follows
Drug Type,Marij Type, Test1 Type,Time / Recv'd

When i write out the dataset to xml using the **GetXml** method of the **dataset.**
Its Created But some extra values are added in element tag.

Its addeding due to special characters like {' / ....etc}

How do i get the resulting xml without those values?

Comment: What extra values? Can you post a sample please.

Comment: Where do you see these extra values, by debugging or on frontend(e.g. ASP.NET)?

Comment: Drug_x0020_Type But it should be Drug Type

Answer (score 0):

With the names you have, you can't.  There are limits to the characters allow in an XML element name.  I don't know all the limits, but spaces and probably most symbols are not allowed.  Spaces in particular make sense to forbid as space is used as the delimiter between the element name and each attribute.